# How to have automatic versioning mechanism of npm package while reading configuration from package.json

Tags: angular, azure, npm, azure-devops, devops

I would like to have such mechnanism to update the version of npm package automatically ( or kinda seed to increment the versioning everytime new paackage is pushed to the feed ). In Azure DevOps, you cannot remove the packages but just deprecate. So the build get fails because it sees the same version of the package already available.

Comment: Could [this](https://medium.com/objectsharp/auto-incrementing-package-versions-during-npm-publish-31dcbbc60c97) be what you want? Use Rest Api to get the version number for your package.

Comment: Exactly, this one is also considering the build directory and using custom command to create a version of the package.

Comment: see my answer, I clarified with similar approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I picked `$(GitVersion.SemVar)` as the package version. This would get the latest git commit and the var `SemVar`will return checked in version. I know this is not mature approach but it''s better than `version.patch` which is just increasing the version.

Answer (score 0):

In general case, you need some external library + either extra git commit to keep track of versions or some storage.

I described some of the possible options here: https://worklifenotes.com/2020/02/27/automatic-version-increments-with-reliza-hub-2-strategies/

(*Disclaimer*: The link describes using Reliza Versioning OSS or Reliza Hub, which are the tools I'm working on, but you may be able to find alternatives using similar principle). Good thing is this approach would work with any CI and any artifact storage (meaning you're not dependent on Azure DevOps or Azure Artifacts).

Also specifically for node you can consider npm-specific tools: [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) or [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I followed build pipeline approach. In the yaml file, took the Git version strategy. Using $(GitVersion.SemVar) will return a new version which can work as package version.